# Integrating the heat equation

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The question I am working on is:

> Suppose $\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial
>  ^2 u}{\partial x^2}+x,u(x,0)=f(x),\frac{\partial u}{\partial
>  x}(0,t)=\beta,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(L,t)=7$.
>
> Calculate the total thermal energy in the one-dimensional rod (as a
>   function of time).

What I tried:

We got a hint from the professor that we should try to calculate the integral:

$\displaystyle \int_0^L \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\ dx= \int_0^L \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2}+x\ dx $

I tried looking up resources on how to integrate a PDE and tried wolfram, but cant figure out where to start on this integral.

Comment: There is a derivative there which you need to integrate.

Comment: Where/which one?

Comment: The second partial derivative in your equation. Of course $x$ is also a derivative.